# How can I intentionally corrupt the geometry of a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, geometry

I am in need of a few shapefiles with bad geometry for testing some Python code. How can I intentionally create bad geometry in a shapefile? Preferably I would be able to create three (point, line, polygon).

Comment: Geometry can be bad in many ways, can you narrow it down?

Comment: I write 'C' code to break geometry, or use `dd` to sew pieces of files together.  You could certainly use Python for the same purpose, but non-conformant shapefiles often invoke *undefined behavior* rules, which make them exceedingly difficult to test (a valid undefined behavior could include production of a black hole that consumes your server).

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Things that would normally be fixed by ArcMAP's repair geometry tool, such as self intersections or unclosed rings.

Comment: See here for discussion http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity and look at the GDAL autotest suite for concrete examples with Python https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/TestingNotes

Comment: I can upload a couple 3rd parties product, line and polygon. Let me know. Create bad point is easy, open table and click after last row

Answer (score 2):

You could use QGIS to edit line and polygon shapefiles. Rightclick a shapelayer then "toggle editing". Use the "node tool" to drag lines across each other to cause intersecting(invalid) geometry. Intersecting line points are even highlighted with bright green 'X's.